# Extracting file name from array element in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have an environment variable like this

```
set BINARY[0]=C:\binary.bin
```

From which I'm trying to extract the full file name

```
set "x=0"
:binloop
if defined BINARY[%x%] (
    call echo %%BINARY[%x%]%%
    FOR %%i IN ("%%BINARY[%x%]%%") DO (
         set FNAME=%%~nxi
    )
    set /a "x+=1"
    GOTO binloop
)
rem ...
```

However for some reason, it tries to do:

```
set FNAME=%BINARY[0]%
```

instead of

```
set FNAME=binary.bin
```

What's wrong with the code and why?

Comment: Use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) rather than `call` and double-`%`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a command prompt window, run `set /?` and read the output help pages explaining when and how to use delayed expansion in a code block for the commands **IF** and **FOR**.

`%%` in a batch file is interpreted as literal percent character which is the reason why a loop variable in a command executed directly in a command prompt window must be specified with just one percent sign while the same loop in a batch file requires two percent signs on referencing the loop variable.

When the Windows command processor encounters an opening parenthesis which marks the beginning of a command block, it searches for the matching closing parenthesis and replaces all environment variables references with syntax `%VariableName%` by the current value of the variable or nothing in case of variable does not exist. Then after the entire command block was parsed the **IF** or **FOR** is executed and used is once or more times the already preprocessed command block.

You could use

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "BINARY[1]=C:\binary1.bin"
set "BINARY[0]=C:\binary0.bin"
set "x=0"

:binloop
if defined BINARY[%x%] (
    call echo %%BINARY[%x%]%%
    for %%i in ("!BINARY[%x%]!") do (
         set FNAME=%%~nxi
         set FNAME
    )
    set /a "x+=1"
    goto binloop
)
endlocal
```

which outputs

```
C:\binary0.bin
FNAME=binary0.bin
C:\binary1.bin
FNAME=binary1.bin
```

The command line

```
call echo %%BINARY[%x%]%%
```

is something special. This line is preprocessed before execution of command **IF** to

```
call echo %BINARY[0]%
```

respectively on second run to

```
call echo %BINARY[1]%
```

By usage of command **CALL** the single command line is processed like a subroutine or another batch file which means the line is preprocessed once more resulting in execution of

```
 echo C:\binary0.bin
```

and on second run in execution of

```
 echo C:\binary1.bin
```

which is the reason why the output is as expected here. But there is no double preprocessing for the environment variable reference in **FOR**.

Much better would be most likely the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "BINARY[1]=C:\binary1.bin"
set "BINARY[0]=C:\binary0.bin"

for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('set "BINARY[" 2^>nul') do (
    set "FNAME=%%~nxJ"
    set FNAME
)

endlocal
```

The command `set` outputs all variables with their name and equal sign and their values which start with the specified string when there is whether parameter `/A` or `/P` used and the parameter does not contain an equal sign in an alphabetically sorted list. So the output of

```
set "BINARY[" 2>nul
```

as used in the command **FOR** is

```
BINARY[0]=C:\binary0.bin
BINARY[1]=C:\binary1.bin
```

which is processed by the **FOR** loop which splits each line into two strings based on first occurrence of the equal sign because of `tokens=1* delims==`. The first string is the variable name assigned to loop variable `I`. And the second string is everything after first equal sign assigned to loop variable `J` being the next character in ASCII table.

`2>nul` is used to suppress the error message output by command **SET** to **STDERR** by redirecting it to device **NUL** if there is no environment variable defined with a name starting with `BINARY[` in any case. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with `^` as otherwise command processor would exit batch processing on this line because of `2>nul` resulting in a syntax error on **FOR** command line at this position.

**Note:** Because of alphabetically sorted output by command **SET** the environment variable `BINARY[10]` is output after `BINARY[0]` and before `BINARY[1]` and `BINARY[2]`. So if the order is important, the first batch solution is needed or the environment variables are created with number in square brackets have all same number of digits with leading zeros, i.e. 00000, 00001, ..., 00002, 00010, 00011, ...

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And see also Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).